# Are non-virtual methods of the baseclass guaranteed to be available through objects of the derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    void Print() { std::cout << "a\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {

};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.Print();
}
```

It prints `a` as expected. However, I'd like to make sure this is indeed valid use of C++ and I'm not accidently running into UB.

Are all non virtual methods inherited by the derived class? And if so, are they guaranteed to be available through an object (or a pointer to an object) of the derived class?

Comment: Yes? Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Derived class instance contains a subobject of base class so you are essentially using base class.

Comment: "I'm not accidently running into UB.". You can shoot yourself in the foot with C++ in various ways, but not *that* easy.

Comment: Do you think a language that makes such a program ill-defined would have survived for 40 years?

Comment: _"Are all non virtual methods inherited by the derived class?"_ Unless the derived class hides them.

Comment: @user7860670 I don't know man. All this C++ craziness is starting to get to my head I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) (emphasis mine):

> When a class uses public member access specifier to derive from a base, *all public members of the base class are accessible as public members of the derived class* and all protected members of the base class are accessible as protected members of the derived class

So yes, in your case, `derived` has a member function named `Print` which is accessible publicly via a `derived` object. The member doesn't have to be virtual.

Also, while *all* members of the base class are inherited by the derived class, only members that are `public`ly inherited will be accessible via a `derived` object.

Answer (score 2):

From the view point of [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), given `d.Print();`, the name `Print` will be examined at the scope of `Derived` (the type of `d`) firstly and not found, then examined at the scope of `Base`, then gets found. After that, overload resolution and accessibility check are performed, as the effect, `Base::Print()` is guaranteed to be called successfully in this case. It has nothing to do with the method is `virtual` or not in this case.

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined.